# Laravel 4 - get raw SQL error message

Tags: postgresql, laravel

I'm using Laravel 4 with Postgres.

If I run the following statement in PGAdmin

```
SELEC * FROM tables
```

I get the following error message

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "selec"
LINE 1: selec * from tables
        ^


********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "selec"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1
```

Now when I run the following query in Laravel 4

```
DB::select("SELEC * FROM tables");
```

I get a whole lot of other extra error messages.

Is it possible to actually get the raw Postgres error message somehow?

Comment: Do you mean you get the orangeWhoops debugger output? Can you show us what the error message you **DO** get is? Can you also show what shows up in your errors logs at `app/storage/logs`? The exception raised on top of the Whoops error screen should have the [relevant information available](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php#L553). Note that you get both the Exception message AND the SQL/Bindings used (which should be better than the stock error message!). I'm curious as to what you're seeing...

Answer (score 1):

How about using [pg_result_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-result-error.php) or maybe even [pg_last_error()](http://php.net/pg_last_error)?

```
$query = DB::select('...');

if($query) {
    //do something
} else {
    return pg_result_error($query);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Into `php artisan tinker` you can do that:

```
try {
    // ...  your code here .. //
} catch ( \Exception $objException ) {
    $arrTrace = $objException->getTrace();
    $query = $arrTrace[0]['args'][0];
    $bindings = $arrTrace[0]['args'][1];
    foreach ($bindings as $i => $binding){
        if ($binding instanceof \DateTime) {
            $bindings[$i] = $binding->format('\'Y-m-d H:i:s\'');
        }
        else if (is_string($binding)) {
            $bindings[$i] = "'$binding'";
        }
        else if (is_bool($binding)) {
            $bindings[$i] = $binding ? 'true' : 'false';   
        }
        else if ( $binding === null ) {
            $bindings[$i] = 'NULL';
        }
    }

    // Insert bindings into query
    $query = str_replace(array('%', '?'), array('%%', '%s'), $query);
    $query = trim( vsprintf($query, $bindings) ) . "\n";

    print $query;

}
```